# Import with custom behavior

Tags: magento2, importexport

I want to create an import entity that will have a custom behavior. All the examples I have seen about custom imports merely mention importing data into a table using the related Model, and that's it. The files I want to use for importing do not only have Table information, but I want the client to be able to import a custom profile for my module, that will include configuration fields together with product attribute data.

In essence, I want to be able to use my own class to handle the import of the new entity type I will create for my module, even if it means parsing the CSV file entirely myself.

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_import">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id" identity="true" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Product Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="duration" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Duration"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="CUSTOM_IMPORT_ID_PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import" label="Custom Import" model="VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Files/Sample**

**custom_import.csv**

```
entity_id,name,duration
,"Name 1",90
2,"Name 3",120
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\SampleFileProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="samples" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_import" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_CustomDataImport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Model/Import**

**CustomImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data as ImportHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data;

/**
 * Class Courses
 */
class CustomImport extends AbstractEntity
{
    const ENTITY_CODE = 'custom_import';
    const TABLE = 'custom_import';
    const ENTITY_ID_COLUMN = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns.
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        'entity_id',
    ];

    /**
     * Valid column names
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        'entity_id',
        'name',
        'duration',
    ];

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * Courses constructor.
     *
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     * @param ImportHelper $importExportData
     * @param Data $importData
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        ImportHelper $importExportData,
        Data $importData,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        Helper $resourceHelper,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        $this->initMessageTemplates();
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return static::ENTITY_CODE;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValidColumnNames(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Row validation
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum): bool
    {
        $name = $rowData['name'] ?? '';
        $duration = (int) $rowData['duration'] ?? 0;

        if (!$name) {
            $this->addRowError('NameIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (!$duration) {
            $this->addRowError('DurationIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }

        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Init Error Messages
     */
    private function initMessageTemplates()
    {
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'NameIsRequired',
            __('The name cannot be empty.')
        );
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'DurationIsRequired',
            __('Duration should be greater than 0.')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Import data
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _importData(): bool
    {
        switch ($this->getBehavior()) {
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE:
                $this->deleteEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntity(): bool
    {
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);

                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowId = $rowData[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                    $rows[] = $rowId;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($rows) {
            return $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace entities
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];

            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $row) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($row, $rowNum)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);

                    continue;
                }

                $rowId = $row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                $rows[] = $rowId;
                $columnValues = [];

                foreach ($this->getAvailableColumns() as $columnKey) {
                    $columnValues[$columnKey] = $row[$columnKey];
                }

                $entityList[$rowId][] = $columnValues;
                $this->countItemsCreated += (int) !isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
                $this->countItemsUpdated += (int) isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
            }
            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE === $behavior) {
                if ($rows && $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows))) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
                }
            } elseif (Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND === $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save entities
     *
     * @param array $entityData
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData): bool
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE);
            $rows = [];

            foreach ($entityData as $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            }

            if ($rows) {
                $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $rows, $this->getAvailableColumns());

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @param array $entityIds
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntityFinish(array $entityIds): bool
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->connection->delete(
                    $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE),
                    $this->connection->quoteInto(static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN . ' IN (?)', $entityIds)
                );

                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAvailableColumns(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
}
```